# How to determine date paid given billing and payment data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to know when a bill was paid to determine how early or late it was paid. Unfortunately, I just have billing creation data and payment records.

### Example 1

```sql
--raw data
WITH bill AS (
  SELECT 'b1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-01') AS created, DATE('2022-01-15') AS due, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b2', DATE('2022-01-01'), DATE('2022-01-30'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b3', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-01-17'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b4', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-02-01'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b5', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-01-19'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b6', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-02-04'), 50
),
payment AS (
  SELECT 'p1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-10') AS made, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p2', DATE('2022-01-11'), 50
)
-- setup
SELECT * FROM bill
```

I want a query that returns all of the data from the bill table plus the date that the bill was paid, which is theoretically derived from the payment table.

In the example above, the solution could be to sort the bill rows by the due date and apply the payments accordingly:

```sql
--raw data
WITH bill AS (
  SELECT 'b1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-01') AS created, DATE('2022-01-15') AS due, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b2', DATE('2022-01-01'), DATE('2022-01-30'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b3', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-01-17'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b4', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-02-01'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b5', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-01-19'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b6', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-02-04'), 50
),
payment AS (
  SELECT 'p1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-10') AS made, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p2', DATE('2022-01-11'), 50
),
--start solution
p AS (
  SELECT
    payment.id,
    payment.made,
    payment.amount,
    SUM( payment.amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY payment.made
    ) AS amount_cumulative
  FROM payment
),
b AS (
  SELECT
    bill.id,
    bill.created,
    bill.due,
    bill.amount,
    SUM( bill.amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY bill.due
    ) AS amount_cumulative
  FROM bill
),
repayments AS (
  SELECT
    b.*,
    p.made,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY b.id
      ORDER BY p.made ASC
    ) AS seq
  FROM b
  LEFT JOIN p
    ON b.amount_cumulative <= p.amount_cumulative
  WHERE p.made IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  b.*,
  repayments.made AS payment_date
FROM b
LEFT JOIN repayments
  ON b.id = repayments.id
WHERE (repayments.seq = 1 OR repayments.seq IS NULL)
ORDER BY b.id
```

[image: Correct answer, but wrong solution]

### Example 2

However, that solution breaks down if we change some of the bill and payment dates (because payments must be applied to the bill with an oustanding balance and the earliest due date at the time of the payment). For example:

```sql
--raw data
WITH bill AS (
  SELECT 'b1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-01') AS created, DATE('2022-01-15') AS due, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b2', DATE('2022-01-01'), DATE('2022-01-30'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b3', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-01-17'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b4', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-02-01'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b5', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-01-19'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b6', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-02-04'), 50
),
payment AS (
  SELECT 'p1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-02') AS made, 100 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p2', DATE('2022-01-11'), 50
),
--start solution
p AS (
  SELECT
    payment.id,
    payment.made,
    payment.amount,
    SUM( payment.amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY payment.made
    ) AS amount_cumulative
  FROM payment
),
b AS (
  SELECT
    bill.id,
    bill.created,
    bill.due,
    bill.amount,
    SUM( bill.amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY bill.due
    ) AS amount_cumulative
  FROM bill
),
repayments AS (
  SELECT
    b.*,
    p.made,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY b.id
      ORDER BY p.made ASC
    ) AS seq
  FROM b
  LEFT JOIN p
    ON b.amount_cumulative <= p.amount_cumulative
  WHERE p.made IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  b.*,
  repayments.made AS payment_date
FROM b
LEFT JOIN repayments
  ON b.id = repayments.id
WHERE (repayments.seq = 1 OR repayments.seq IS NULL)
ORDER BY b.id
```

[image: Problem with the solution]

This example is even trickier if `p1` is for an `amount` = 75 (in which case `b2` should remain not completely paid, but `b3` should be paid in full on `2022-01-11`).

### Trickiest Example

This is the most contrived, but it best illustrates the problem. Payment 1 goes toward Bill 1 because that is the only available bill at the time of the payment (the payment almost pays the first bill in full). At the time of Payment 2, the bill with the earliest unpaid balance is now Bill 2, so all of the payment goes toward Bill 2 (and again, the payment almost pays the second bill in full). However, at the end of this sequence, 99/100 is paid toward Bill 1 and 49/50 is paid toward Bill 2, but neither Bill 1 nor Bill 2 are paid in full, so the paid in full date should be NULL for both.

```sql
--raw data
WITH bill AS (
  SELECT 'b1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-01') AS created, DATE('2022-01-15') AS due, 100 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b2', DATE('2022-01-02'), DATE('2022-01-14'), 50
),
payment AS (
  SELECT 'p1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-10') AS made, 99 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p2', DATE('2022-01-11'), 49
),
-- setup
SELECT * FROM bill
```

## Question

Can I get the `payment_date` with a query? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: Just to confirm, your logic is the earliest payment date should be matched with the earliest due date per payment id? Ex. p1 is closest to b1, then assign payment date. p2 is closest to b3, then assign payment date.

Comment: I think you understand the problem correctly. I think it is somewhat logical, but we apply payments to the bill(s) that has(/have) the earliest/oldest due date(s) at the time that the payment is made -- assuming that they still have an outstanding balance. So if you make a payment on day 1 and there is only one bill, the payment will go entirely toward bill 1. If you make a payment on day 4 and there are two bills created (aka posted) by day 4, then the payment will first go to pay any remaining balance on bill 1 before looking to apply any leftover toward paying bill 2.

Comment: There seems to be some discrepancy in two examples. In e.g. 2 why payment is being early for due date of 30th? (Its quoted as error and should be 2022-01-02).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer query below. Idea is to distribute payments over range.

```
--raw data
WITH bill AS (
  SELECT 'b1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-01') AS created, DATE('2022-01-15') AS due, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b2', DATE('2022-01-01'), DATE('2022-01-30'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b3', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-01-17'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b4', DATE('2022-01-03'), DATE('2022-02-01'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b5', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-01-19'), 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b6', DATE('2022-01-05'), DATE('2022-02-04'), 50
), payment AS (
  SELECT 'p1' AS id, DATE('2022-01-10') AS made, 50 AS amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 'p2', DATE('2022-01-11'), 50
), b as (
-- setup
  SELECT
    bill.id,
    bill.created,
    bill.due,
    bill.amount,
    SUM( bill.amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY bill.created, bill.due
    ) AS amount_cumulative_created,
    SUM( bill.amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY bill.due
    ) as amount_cumulative_due,
    row_number() over (order by bill.due) crn
  FROM bill
  order by created
), p as (
   SELECT
    p.id,
    p.made,
    p.amount,
    case when 
      row_number() over (order by 0) = 
      max(un) over (partition by p.id) then
        floor(p.amount / max(un) over (partition by p.id)) + 
        mod(p.amount, max(un) over (partition by p.id))
      else
        floor(p.amount / max(un) over (partition by p.id)) 
    end new_amount,
    row_number() over (order by 0) prn
  FROM 
    (select *,
    row_number() over (order by payment.made) prn 
    from payment) p join b
    on p.prn = b.crn
,unnest(generate_array(1,
(select coalesce(max(b.crn),0)+1 from b
where p.amount > b.amount_cumulative_due
and p.made between b.created and b.due),
1)) un
), p_distrib as (
  select *,
    SUM( p.new_amount ) OVER (
      ORDER BY p.prn
    ) AS payment_cumulative, from p
)
select b.*, 
(select min(pd.made) from p_distrib pd
 where
--- Adjust here for what date takes preference - created vs. due.
--- Replace amount_cumulative_created  with amount_cumulative_due as needed
 b.amount_cumulative_created <= pd.payment_cumulative
 and pd.made between b.created and b.due)
from b;
```

[image]

Comment: Good to know. Adjusted the spellings.

Comment: I hate to uncheck this answer, but I realized that it is not quite doing what I expected and I have not immediately figured out how to solve it. An example payment sequence that is a problem: 75 on Jan 1 and then 25 on Jan 3. That would pay off bill 1 on Jan 1 and put 25 toward bill 2. Then on Jan 3, the next payment would only go entirely toward bill 3 because it is due earlier than bill 2.

Comment: I think what has to happen is that each payment needs to be (potentially split up) and assigned to a bill or bills and then those sub-payments need to be tracked to monitor the progress on repaying each bill. It seems iterative, which is why I am not sure if it can be reasonably done in a query.

Comment: There could be an issue based on your specific requirement; however, I tried with what you mentioned and its coming out fine. I've posted as image in solution, please refer and post back what needs adjustment in that and I will try to fix.

Comment: Thanks! I added the "Trickiest Example" above, which is completely contrived, but helps to illustrate the crux of the payment allocation issue. If you have time to think about it some more, I would be very grateful. If not, I will keep banging my head against the wall :)